# How can I install Ubuntu on my computer?

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot

I have tried windows 8 cp in my past. I want to install linux ubuntu on my computer for now.

I have uninstall win8 but I am not sure about if they have affected my boot setting. actually I am using Win 2008 r2 server and it's work fine after uninstall win8.

Now If I am boot from wubi it's not show me any option. they goes restarted as normal. how I can install linux on my computer. Any idea.

I have tried to run wubi.exe but it's not worked and restart worked as normal. I want to get dual boot in my system. where one have windows and second have linux ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does your computer have an Optical drive?  You know... a CD/DVD drive?
2. Can you download a [disc image of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)?
3. Do you have access to blank discs?
4. Do you have the ability to burn a disc from this ISO of Ubuntu that you have downloaded?

If the answer is Yes to all 4 of these questions, then you can simply... download an ISO of Ubuntu, burn a disc from that image you downloaded, boot your computer to the disc, and once it loads, follow the installation instructions to erase your hard drive and replace it with Ubuntu.

You said nothing about wanting to set up a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: I have access to optical drive. I have download ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.

Comment: well, that addresses two of the four points I brought up.

Comment: any idea for getting it done without CD.

Comment: @user33631: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick